# Multiple inputs - Mocking (Pytest)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mocking, pytest

I am having a hard time mocking my inputs to get the baseline of my Pytest. I simply want to mock my inputs for my main function so that the rest of my Pytest uses those inputs as its baseline for all my other functions (I have other functions that depend on main()'s inputs to get going). Below I have provided 2 pictures:

1. My test file with my trial to get something right
2. My main function which requires inputs.

It's been quite frustrating for some weeks now, and I have tried many solutions coming from Youtube videos to forums but nothing is working (I have been stuck on the same error each time).

All the help is extremely appreciated!

(FYI: I am a 5-week newborn in coding, please be easy on me!)

[image: Error code while running Pytest]

[image: My main() function]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - instead, please paste them into the question as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This definitely sounds frustrating! What would be really helpful for us is if you could try your best to implement what you want, then post the actual error messages you’re seeing. It’s way easier for us to debug a specific error than to guess how to complete your code. Check out the guide to [ask].